# log4J2 Store and use variables / lookup-values

Tags: java, variables, log4j2, lookup

In my java program I want to use several log files.

So according to the log4j documentation I would assume that lookup values are use to do that.

The [Lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html) page describe how to build the configuration files. But has only little information about how to store the values so that the configuration file is retrieving the values.

So I want to have logfilename dynamically filled.

Test with envrimonment works:

```
<File name="MyFile" fileName="${env:USERERNAME}" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</File>
```

I would assume that `System.getProperty("USER")` would match the java lookup `${java:USER}` but it does not work.

I tested both variables using:

```
System.out.println("USER: " + System.getProperty("USER"));
System.out.println("USERNAME: " + System.getenv("USERNAME"));
```

**So how to fill the variables for**

- Context Map Lookup
- Java lookup

Which are the differences?

Comment: is it not only a typo ? (you wrote `${env:USERERNAME}`)

Comment: no - i edited the question to clarify

Comment: I meant in your config: `<File name="MyFile" fileName="${env:USERERNAME}" [...]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways of lookup in `log4j2`. Let me add some details to them -

**Context Map Lookup -**  For putting value using context map, use below code -

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.put("logFileName", "app.log");
```

Variable can be accessed in configuration file using `${ctx:logFileName}` or `%X{logFileName}`.

Context map lookup is generally used in web application where you want some value for each user request  i.e. for each `thread`.

**Environment Lookup -** Environment lookup is used for looking up system environment variables like `USERNAME`, `PLATFORM`. You can print all environment variables in Java using below -

```
System.out.println(System.getenv());
```

OR any specific environment variable -

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"));
```

However, from Java program, you can not set environment variables.

As you mentioned in your code, environment variables can be accessed using `${env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}` syntax.

**Java Lookup -** Java lookup is for Java environment information like `java version`, `hardware` etc. Variables are fixed and can not be set in java program.

Such variables can be accessed using `${java:vm}` syntax where `vm` is java environment related variable name.

**System Properties Lookup -** It is easy to get and set such properties using below code -

```
System.setProperty("logFileName", "app.log");
System.getProperty("logFileName");
```

Variables can be accessed in log4j2 configuration file using `${sys:logFileName}` syntax.

Good thing about these system properties is you can pass these properties as `VM Arguments` to your program like `-DlogFileName=app3.log`.

There are other lookup mechanism also like **Date Lookup**, **Map Lookup** etc which are mostly used. Rest details can be checked [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html)

---

Since you want to set file name dynamically in your application and if you want to set file name only once, I would suggest to you `System property`. But ensure that, you set `System Property` before initializing `log4j`

Comment: Very good simple and even detailed explanation - muchas gracias